# The "max" function on Tikz being annoying, help?

Tags: tikz-pgf, debugging, bugs

I used Tikz to chart the following function.

[image]

This is fine, except that I want the function to equal 0 instead of negative values. So I tried using "max(0,f(x))", where f(x) is my function (specified below):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz} 
    \usepackage{fp} 
    \usetikzlibrary{fixedpointarithmetic} 
    \begin{document} 
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (4,4); 
    \draw[
            samples=100,
            fixed point arithmetic,
            scale=1.3,domain=0.001:4,smooth,variable=\x,blue] plot
                ({\x},{max(0,(\x*(0.005*\x)^0.5-0.005)/((0.33*\x+(0.005*\x)^0.5)))});  
    \end{tikzpicture}   
    \end{document}
```

But this code does not run. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just for the records: your code does not compile on my machine. Does it run thought on yours? Which TeX installation are you using?

Comment: The same issue arises with `min` as well. (I tried to see what's going on by comparing min and max in pgflibraryfixedpointarithmetic.code.tex, just to discover that they do not differ, and min doesn't work as well.)

Comment: What is also odd is that `fp` *does* come with min and max, they are in `\FPmin` and `\FPmax`.

Comment: @marmot try without `max`, I think it will compile. Let me know if otherwise.

Comment: @Raaja Yes, of course, without `max` (or `min`) it compiles. But that's not the issue, I think. Rather, I think pafnuti has discovered an important bug. (However, the fact that some of us can compile and others not seems to suggest that there are different versions of the `fp` package at work. I added some `\typeout`s to sort of substantiate that.)

Comment: @marmot by the way its evolving, I think so too :P Just added some extra tags to that question, lets see.

Comment: Ulrike Fischer shared [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/215084/121799) with me ... seems to be known issue....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Removing the `fixed point arithmetic` should ensure you get what you want. because, when you specify the `fixed point` constraint, the `max(.)` assumes its domain to be integers (I think). However,  your function returns real-values. Hence, this will cause an internal contradiction and hence you see the errors. If you now remove the constraints, all should go as you desire. Below is the `MWE` based solution for that.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{fp} 
\begin{document} 
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (4,4); 
    \draw[
    samples=100,
    scale=1.3,domain=0.001:4,smooth,variable=\x,blue] plot ({\x},{max(0,(\x*(0.005*\x)^0.5-0.005)/((0.33*\x+(0.005*\x)^0.5)))});
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

which will give you:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that it assumes integers? And even if that's the case, how would that explain that `max(0,...)` yields something negative?

Comment: @marmot if it's wrong (I sense it from your question), please correct me. What I understood from OP's question is that when OP uses no `max` they get negative range, but when OP uses `max` tje code doesn't work. By making that assumption on `fixed point` it worked. But I have not read that in the manual. Also, in here, I do not know how to see the output data.

Comment: I have not much experience with that library but I would be *really* surprised if it assumed integers. And, even if it did, it would not explain the fact that `max(0,...)` can become negative, would it? In addition, there is is [@Bamboo's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445503/121799), which is at odds with that assumption.

Comment: @marmot I'm in agreement with you. OP tried wo `max` and gets the negative, but when tried with `max` it results in error.

Answer (score 5):

Using an `ifthenelse` conditional, the result is good with or without `fixed point arithmetic`. I guess this supports @marmot interrogations regarding the `max` function.

As proposed by @marmot, I also included a redefinition of the `max` function as `Max(x,y)` based on `ifthenelse` to avoid the repetition of the tested function.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz} 
    \usepackage{fp} 
    \usetikzlibrary{fixedpointarithmetic} 
    \begin{document} 
    \tikzset{declare function={Max(\X,\Y)=ifthenelse(\X>\Y,\X,\Y);}}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (4,4); 
    \draw[
            samples=100,
            fixed point arithmetic,
            scale=1.3,domain=0.001:4,
            smooth,
            variable=\x,blue] plot
                ({\x},{Max(((\x*(0.005*\x)^0.5-0.005)/((0.33*\x+(0.005*\x)^0.5))),
                                  0)});  
    \end{tikzpicture}   
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'm wondering if you could the same for `min`? ;-)

Comment: @marmot What do you mean ?